# urllib freeze if url is too big !

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

ok im trying to open a url using urllib but the problem is that the file is too big, so when i open the url python freezes, im also using wxpython which also freezes when i open the url
my cpu goes to almost 100%  when the url is opened

any solutions ? 
is there a way i can open the url in chunks and maybe have a time.sleep(0.5) in there so it does not freeze ?
this is my code :

```
f = open("hello.txt",'wb')
datatowrite = urllib.urlopen(link).read()
f.write(datatowrite)
f.close()
```

Thanks

Comment: How big are we talkin' here...?

Comment: Ah. So this is just a matter of not wanting to lock your UI during the download? I assume it completes a download of that size *eventually*...? Sounds like you want asynchronous downloads.

Comment: A single-threaded GUI program will always freeze when the main thread is doing something slow.

Comment: @Shog9 yes the url does open, but the problem is that the whole thing freeze. would you mind giving me an example of how 'asynchronous downloads' work in python ?

Answer (score 1):

You want to split the download into a separate thread, so your UI thread continues to work while the download thread does the work separately. That way you don't get the "freeze" while the download happens.

Read more about threading here:

http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html

Alternatively, you could use the system to download the file outside of python using curl or wget.