# asynchronous downloads with wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, urllib

ok so one of my functions is to open a url and read its contents and then write it in a file
the problem is when i do that my UI freezes i know that i need to use asynchronous downloads but i dont seem to understand exatcly how to ! 
the url im openining is about 10-20 mg
also would http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html help me in any way ?
my code :

```
f = open("hello.txt",'wb')
datatowrite = urllib.urlopen(link).read()
f.write(datatowrite)
f.close()
```

an example would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [urllib freeze if url is too big !](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565910/urllib-freeze-if-url-is-too-big)

Comment: Modify your previous question with the new information, rather than re-asking the same question in a slightly different form.

Comment: Also pretty similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668257/python-simple-async-download-of-url-content

Answer (score 0):

You can use the asynhttp client to do this, since you can't be bothered to read the docs on threading.

http://code.google.com/p/asynhttp/

Comment: i asked for an example and no one gave me one !, im new to programming and i dont quite understand the page you linked me to !

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example.  The `10` in the call to `asyncDownload` is the timeout period in seconds.  You'll want to increase that, or possibly get rid of it altogether.  The download results are stored under `thread.dataToWrite`.

```
import threading
import urllib2 as ul

class asyncDownload(threading.Thread):

   def __init__(self,url,http_timeout):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.url = url
      self.http_timeout = http_timeout

   def run(self):
      self.dataToWrite = ul.urlopen(self.url,timeout=self.http_timeout).read()


url = 'http://www.yahoo.com'
thread = asyncDownload(url,10)
thread.run()
print('this thread is still running')
```

Comment: thank you for the example, i dont know if im missing something, but when i run the code and replace the url to the one that i have, it does not seem to be doing anything more than the usual !, i mean when i run the code it still freezes python and wxpython which is what im trying to prevent, also i played with the time out (10) and that did not seem to change anything, i used time.time() to see if there was  a difference in the time it took for the file to be read and it was the same if the timeout was 1 or 100000 ! thanks again for the example though

Answer (score 0):

You need to take that threading example that was given and combine it in a wxPython program. You can use the example on this site and basically modify it slightly to use the new threading example: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

```
import wx
import thread

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.btn = wx.Button(self, label="Start")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.btn, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)

    def onButton(self, evt):
        self.btn.Enable(False)
        thread.start_new_thread(self.longRunning, ())

    def onLongRunDone(self):
        print "finished my task, I may want to update GUI elements here"
        self.btn.Enable(True)

    def longRunning(self):
        f = open("hello.txt",'wb')
        datatowrite = urllib.urlopen(link).read()
        f.write(datatowrite)
        f.close()
        wx.CallAfter(self.onLongRunDone)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    app.TopWindow = MainFrame(None)
    app.TopWindow.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```